# How to pass data to an email template that is sent via Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm using Rails, Mongoid and Sidekiq in this app.

In my Mailer I have the following:

```
def send_invoice(invoice, domain)
  @invoice = Invoice.find(invoice)
  @user = User.find(domain)
  attachments["invoice.pdf"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/invoices/pdf/55f5c596019e2b51af000000-55f82b520540a78f43000000.pdf")
  mail to: "wagner.matos@mac.com", subject: "Invoice from MyJarvis", reply_to: @user.email, :from => @user.email, :bcc => 'wagner.matos@mac.com'
end
```

And in my email template I have something like this (haml):

```
!!!
%html
  = "Hello #{@invoice[:name]}"
```

And if I use ActiveMailer (not using Sidekiq) all works fine. Now in my worker:

```
def perform(data, count)
  message = JSON.load(data)
  UserMailer.send_invoice(message['invoice'], message['domain']).deliver
end
```

Then I get an error saying `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

After some investigation I found out that the problem is with the variable used in the email. When I tried the same email without using the variable, all worked fine.

Now I understand this is an issue on how Sidekiq stores data in Redis (as json). What I don't know is, how can I pass variables to the email template using Sidekiq?

**EDIT: Here's my Mailer and my Worker:**

Mailer:

```
def send_invoice(invoice, domain)
  @invoice = Invoice.find(invoice)
  @user = User.find(domain)
  attachments["invoice.pdf"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/invoices/pdf/55f5c596019e2b51af000000-55f82b520540a78f43000000.pdf")
  mail to: "email@example.com", subject: "Invoice", reply_to: @user.email, :from => @user.email
end
```

Worker:

```
def perform(data, count)
  message = JSON.load(data)
  UserMailer.send_invoice(message['invoice'], message['domain']).deliver
end
```

And in my controller:

```
...
h = JSON.generate({ 'invoice' => @invoice.id.to_s, 'domain' => set_db })
PostmanWorker.perform_async(h, 1)
...
```

So as you can see I'm passing the id for it to be processed inside the worker rather than passing a Hash. But how can I pass the `@invoice` hash to the email template?

Comment: You probably need to pass `invoice_id` (or whatever identifies your data) and retrieve it inside the worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job), there is a newer syntax (API) for delivering email:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later!(wait: 1.hour)
```

Checkout the section under "Action Mailer", as that may solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried a slightly different syntax: `UserMailer.delay_for(1.minutes).send_invoice(@invoice.id.to_s, set_db)` which didn't work. I'll try your suggestion in bit and let you know

Comment: I've tried your approach but unfortunately got the same error as the variable created in the Mailer was not passed to email template. If I try without any variable in my email template, the email is delivered ok, but that's not what I want to achieve.